# Redis Expiration not working

Tags: java, database, algorithm, redis, nosql

I am using Redis Pub/Sub model (https://redis.io/topics/pubsub), and I am using jedis client for the same. I have subscribed to redis expiration. This works perfectly when redis has smaller number of keys. But if I have >1 million keys with different TTL, then the expiration of the keys does not always happen according to the TTL of the key.

From the redis documentation (https://redis.io/commands/expire) :

```
Specifically this is what Redis does 10 times per second:
1. Test 20 random keys from the set of keys with an associated expire.
2. Delete all the keys found expired.
3. If more than 25% of keys were expired, start again from step 1.
```

So with large number of keys it is possible that the random keys chosen have a higher TTL and hence the steps 2 and 3 don't get executed.

How do I solve this, or can I use something other than redis, to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is mentioned on [Redis Keyspace Notifications](https://redis.io/topics/notifications) page.

> If no command targets the key constantly, and there are many keys with
>   a TTL associated, there can be a significant delay between the time
>   the key time to live drops to zero, and the time the expired event is
>   generated.

To solve this, you can try increasing frequency of active expiration events using `hz` config value, which defaults to 10 times per second.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, we decided to use a different redis database which only contains keys with the same TTL.

We continue to use the default database (index 0) for all other keys (no requiring an expiration notification for example...)